# How to Fix Strong name signature not valid for this assembly FastReport.dll

Tags: .net, fastreport

PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows             : 10.0.22621.0 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
System.Deployment.dll       : 4.8.9176.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_B
clr.dll             : 4.8.9181.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_C
dfdll.dll           : 4.8.9176.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_B
dfshim.dll          : 10.0.22621.30000 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

SOURCES
Deployment url          : file://192.168.0.2/Public/WSEXE/WTERP.application
Application url         : file://192.168.0.2/Public/WSEXE/Application%20Files/WTERP_1_0_0_43/WTERP.exe.manifest

IDENTITIES
Deployment Identity     : WTERP.application, Version=1.0.0.43, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=762b6c184d2fbeac, processorArchitecture=msil
Application Identity        : WTERP.exe, Version=1.0.0.43, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=762b6c184d2fbeac, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
* Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of \192.168.0.2\Public\WSEXE\WTERP.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
+ Strong name signature not valid for this assembly FastReport.dll.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
* [9/22/2023 11:38:09 AM] : Activation of \192.168.0.2\Public\WSEXE\WTERP.application has started.
* [9/22/2023 11:38:09 AM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
* [9/22/2023 11:38:09 AM] : Installation of the application has started.
* [9/22/2023 11:38:09 AM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
* [9/22/2023 11:38:12 AM] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
* [9/22/2023 11:38:12 AM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.

ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [9/22/2023 11:38:42 AM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (SignatureValidation)
- Strong name signature not valid for this assembly FastReport.dll.
- Source: System.Deployment
- Stack trace:
at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyStrongNameAssembly(String filePath, AssemblyManifest assemblyManifest)
at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyComponents()
at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
No transaction information is available.

PLATFORM VERSION INFO Windows : 10.0.22621.0 (Win32NT) Common Language Runtime : 4.0.30319.42000